# Allow `UIView` to get tapped inside the path masked to its layer. How?

Tags: ios, swift

I've a `UIView` masked to draw a hexagon and have added a `UITapGesture` to it. I don't want to handle the tap outside the boundaries of that `Hexagon`. What are the suitable ways to achieve this? Please provide me your valuable suggestion. Thanks

[image]

**Code To Draw `Hexagon`**

```
extension UIView
{
    func hexagonLayers()
    {
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/3, 0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*2/3, 0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height/3))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height*2/3))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*2/3, self.frame.size.height))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/3, self.frame.size.height))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height*2/3))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height/3))
        path.closePath()

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting tap inside a bezier path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691891/detecting-tap-inside-a-bezier-path)

Answer (score 1):

Try `- (BOOL)containsPoint:(CGPoint)point` ,it may be useful in your case.

Also be careful if you get gesture point from superview, the coordinate may not be correct with your test. You have a method to convertPoint from or to a particular view's coordinate system:

```
 - (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view
 - (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point fromView:(UIView *)view
```

Comment: can you please show me how to access the bezierPath from the view?

Answer (score 0):

There 4 corner cropped for making a hexagon shape. These 4 corners can be treated as 4 corner triangles. Now you need to detect the click point inside button lies in triangles or hexagon area.

I have done this by detecting the points for triangle and check whether the click point is lies inside any of the triangle or hexagon area of the button.

```
@IBAction func didSelectHexaButton(sender:UIButton, event:UIEvent)
        {
            let ifInside:Bool  = sender.touchInside(event)

            if(ifInside)
            {
                //TODO button code
                print("button point handled")
            }
            else
            {
                print("clicked out side")
                // Cornert point clicked
            }
        } 

    func touchInside(event: UIEvent) ->Bool
        {
            let touches:NSSet = event.touchesForView(self)!;
            let touch:UITouch = touches.allObjects.first as! UITouch
            let point:CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self)

            let height = self.frame.size.height / 3;
            let width = self.frame.size.width / 3;

            //uper left triange
            let inside_1:Bool  = self.PointInTriangle(point, v1: CGPointZero, v2: CGPointMake(0, height), v3: CGPointMake(width , 0))
            let inside_2:Bool  = self.PointInTriangle(point, v1: CGPointMake(width * 2, 0), v2: CGPointMake(width * 3 , 0), v3: CGPointMake(width * 3 , height))
            let inside_3:Bool  = self.PointInTriangle(point, v1: CGPointMake(0, height * 2), v2: CGPointMake(0, height * 3), v3: CGPointMake(width , height * 3))
            let inside_4:Bool  = self.PointInTriangle(point, v1: CGPointMake(width * 2, height * 3), v2: CGPointMake(width * 3, height * 3), v3: CGPointMake(width * 3 , height * 2))

            return !inside_1 && !inside_2 && !inside_3 && !inside_4
        }

        func sign (p1:CGPoint, p2:CGPoint, p3:CGPoint) -> CGFloat
        {
            return (p1.x - p3.x) * (p2.y - p3.y) - (p2.x - p3.x) * (p1.y - p3.y);
        }

        func PointInTriangle (point:CGPoint, v1:CGPoint, v2:CGPoint, v3:CGPoint) -> Bool
        {

            var b1:Bool, b2:Bool, b3:Bool;

            b1 = self.sign(point, p2: v1, p3: v2) < 0.0
            b2 = self.sign(point, p2: v2, p3: v3) < 0.0
            b3 = self.sign(point, p2: v3, p3: v1) < 0.0

            return ((b1 == b2) && (b2 == b3 ));
        }
```